# How to change a MD5 password for an admin/control panel in phpMyAdmin? (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, hash, phpmyadmin, md5

I have a php site with an admin area, on setup I selected a simple password. E.g. '123456'. This was not intended to be a permanent solution.

When it comes to changing the password on my database using phpMyAdmin, this is where I become stuck. I used MD5 to generate a password (this fact might not be relevant), so if I update the password in my database say to another MD5 hashed password. E.g. 'newpassword' ('5e9d11a14ad1c8dd77e98ef9b53fd1ba') save it. It actually is making no difference to my admin login area.

Although the database is updated, the password remains as previous, in this example '123456'.

There must be something else that needs updating but not sure where to start looking.

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: include your code so we can identify your issue!

Comment: MD5 is not really suitable these days for password storage. Are you doing any per-row salting at all? Either way, it is probably a good idea for you to switch over to `password_hash()`, which is now built into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- Check if your script create caches (delete caches in this case).
- Call script's support with your problem

Another solution I can't offer because I don't know what script do you use.